# Improve query speed suggestions

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

For self education I am developing an invoicing system for an electricity company. I have multiple time series tables, with different intervals. One table represents consumption, two others represent prices. A third price table should be still incorporated. Now I am running calculation queries, but the queries are slow. I would like to improve the query speed, especially since this is only the beginning calculations and the queries will only become more complicated. Also please note that this is my first database i created and exercises I have done. A simplified explanation is preferred. Thanks for any help provided.

I have indexed: `DATE, PERIOD_FROM, PERIOD_UNTIL` in each table. This speed up the process from 60 seconds to 5 seconds.

> The structure of the tables is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `apxprice` (
 `APX_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `PERIOD_FROM` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `PERIOD_UNTIL` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `PRICE` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`APX_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=28728 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `imbalanceprice` (
 `imbalanceprice_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `PTU` tinyint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `PERIOD_FROM` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `PERIOD_UNTIL` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `UPWARD_INCIDENT_RESERVE` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `DOWNWARD_INCIDENT_RESERVE` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `UPWARD_DISPATCH` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `DOWNWARD_DISPATCH` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `INCENTIVE_COMPONENT` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `TAKE_FROM_SYSTEM` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `FEED_INTO_SYSTEM` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `REGULATION_STATE` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `HOUR` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`imbalanceprice_id`),
 KEY `DATE` (`DATE`,`PERIOD_FROM`,`PERIOD_UNTIL`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=117427 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin

CREATE TABLE `powerload` (
 `powerload_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `EAN` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
 `DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `PERIOD_FROM` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `PERIOD_UNTIL` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `POWERLOAD` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`powerload_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=61039 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin
```

Now when running this query:

```
SELECT  i.DATE, i.PERIOD_FROM, i.TAKE_FROM_SYSTEM, i.FEED_INTO_SYSTEM,
        a.PRICE, p.POWERLOAD, sum(a.PRICE * p.POWERLOAD)
    FROM  imbalanceprice i, apxprice a, powerload p
    WHERE  i.DATE = a.DATE
      and  i.DATE = p.DATE
      AND  i.PERIOD_FROM >= a.PERIOD_FROM
      and  i.PERIOD_FROM = p.PERIOD_FROM
      AND  i.PERIOD_FROM < a.PERIOD_UNTIL
      AND  i.DATE >= '2018-01-01'
      AND  i.DATE <= '2018-01-31'
    group by  i.DATE
```

I have run the query with explain and get the following result: Select_type, all simple partitions all null possible keys a,p = null i = DATE Key a,p = null i = DATE key_len a,p = null i = 8 ref a,p = null i = timeseries.a.DATE,timeseries.p.PERIOD_FROM rows a = 28727 p = 61038 i = 1 filtered a = 100 p = 10 i = 100 a extra: using where using temporary using filesort b extra: using where using join buffer (block nested loop) c extra: null

Preferably I run a more complicated query for a whole year and group by month for example with all price tables incorporated. However, this would be too slow. I have indexed: DATE, PERIOD_FROM, PERIOD_UNTIL in each table. The calculation result may not be changed, in this case quarter hourly consumption of two meters multiplied by hourly prices.

Comment: You should consider learning and using modern join syntax.

Comment: A) Use `JOIN`. B) Use `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: From the looks of the conditions involved, it looks like `a` and `p` are unrelated outside of their relation to `i`. Keep in mind that if there are two `a` and three `p` for a particular `i`, you will get six results for that `i`; `i` with every combination of it's related `a` and `p` records. Also worth noting is that an index on (DATE, PERIOD_FROM, PERIOD_UNTIL) is not the same as separate indexes on each field; and MySQL will only use one from each table in a single query _(which is why it is usually best to just include the actual, full CREATE for the tables in your question.)_.

Comment: Please POST text results of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ........ for analysis as well as SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name(s) and SHOW INDEX FROM table_name(s) involved in the query.

Comment: Please learn the formatting tools for this site; the `EXPLAIN` is unreadable.

Comment: @rickjames Where can I find the 'formatting tools for this site'?  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck - Scroll down this page to the box after "Your Answer" and click on the question mark in its upper right.  Unfortunately, there is no "good" way to do `EXPLAIN`, but I prefer copying the text (not image) and indenting 4 spaces.  That way, the columns line up (but horiz scrolling is a nuisance).

Answer (score 0):

"Categorically speaking," the first thing you should look at is *indexes.*

Your clauses such as `WHERE i.DATE = a.DATE ...` are categorically known as *INNER JOINs,* and the SQL engine needs to have the ability to locate the matching rows "instantly."  (That is to say, without looking through the entire table!)

- *FYI:* Just like any index in real-life – here I would be talking about "library card catalogs" if we still had such a thing – indexes will assist both "equal to" and "less/greater than" queries. The index takes the computer *directly* to a particular point in the data, whether that's a "hit" or a "near miss."

Finally, the `EXPLAIN` verb is very useful:  put that word in front of your query, and the SQL engine should "explain to you" exactly *how* it intends to carry out your query.  (The SQL engine looks at the structure of the database to make that decision.)  Although the `EXPLAIN` output is ... *(heh)* ... "not exactly standardized," it *will* help you to see if the computer thinks that it needs to do something very time-wasting in order to deliver your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have read already about the joins, however, from what I read online this would not speed up the query. It would make the query more readable for other people. I will try and convert the query into a join query.

Comment: Regarding the "Explain" functionality, this is new to me. I have run the query with explain and get the following result:

Select_type, all simple
partitions all null
possible keys a,p = null i = DATE
Key a,p = null i = DATE
key_len a,p = null i = 8 
ref a,p = null i = timeseries.a.DATE,timeseries.p.PERIOD_FROM
rows a = 28727 p = 61038 i = 1 
filtered a = 100 p = 10 i = 100
a extra: using where using temporary using filesort
b extra: using where using join buffer (block nested loop)
c extra: null